# Display Hadoop (1.2.1) results to web page

Tags: hadoop

Currently, I try to write a Hadoop mapreduce function to search list of image from user's input (I already done this step) and want to show results from Hadoop mapreduce to web page (similar when we do search in Google image), but i dont know how to use Java servlet to execute Map reduce function as well as get result to display them on web page.

Could anyone give me some suggestion about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your servlet request to hadoop, and return the result of map/reduce function to the servlet, at last show the result on the web. Because hadoop web page could not show the result of map/reduce function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I need a code example to do that. Do you have any good examples?

Comment: I haven't do such project, I just finish servlet and hadoop project respectlly. I am sorry